# Trouble with read line script in Cygwin

Tags: bash, shell-script, cygwin

I'm on windows 7 using Cygwin.

My script and text file are located in the same directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read name; do
echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < /home/Matt/servers.txt
```

I get this error and I don't know why because this is correct while loop syntax..?

```
u0146121@U0146121-TPD-A ~/Matt
$ ./script.sh
./script.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./script.sh: line 4: `done < /home/Matt/servers.txt'
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think its because I'm on windows and using Cygwin.

Comment: It should work. can you check complete path of your home from cygwin prompt by going to `/home/Matt/`. please note that your home would be under `C:\cygwin\home\matt`.  It is case sensitive when you access from cygwin.

Comment: You have CR-LF line ending in the script. Change it to LF only (edit with vim, `:set notextmode :wq`) and all works.

Comment: @ott--I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @Salton Not sure what you are asking either.

Comment: You can also try `flip -u script.sh` to remove CR LF

Comment: Editing/Creating your scripts via the Cygterm shell (with an editor like nano or vi) should prevent this in the future. Don't use Windows Notepad or Wordpad to write shell scripts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81358/26112) by [ott--](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28180/ott), your script has `CR LF` line endings. This is more visible with `od`.

```
$ od -c script
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \r  \n   w   h   i
0000020   l   e       r   e   a   d       n   a   m   e   ;       d   o
0000040  \r  \n   e   c   h   o       "   N   a   m   e       r   e   a
0000060   d       f   r   o   m       f   i   l   e       -       $   n
0000100   a   m   e   "  \r  \n   d   o   n   e       <       /   h   o
0000120   m   e   /   M   a   t   t   /   s   e   r   v   e   r   s   .
0000140   t   x   t  \r  \n
0000145
```

As you can see, you have `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (line feed) characters at the end of each line where you should only have `\n` characters. This is a result of a compatibility issue between Windows and *nix systems. Bash has difficulty dealing with the `\r` characters.

You can fix your script by using a utility like `dos2unix` or by running the following line.

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' script
```

Comment: That was my problem. Thanks for providing an easy way to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

This is your script with hexdump

```
00000000  23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 62  61 73 68 0d 0a 77 68 69  |#!/bin/bash..whi|
00000010  6c 65 20 72 65 61 64 20  6e 61 6d 65 3b 20 64 6f  |le read name; do|
00000020  0d 0a 65 63 68 6f 20 22  4e 61 6d 65 20 72 65 61  |..echo "Name rea|
```

The lines end with `0d 0a` aka `CR LF`. Change it to `0a` or `LF` only.

Answer (score 1):

The file you're using has windows style line feeds (CR) at the end of them (same thing happened to me using Cygwin on Windows XP).

Use 'dos2unix.exe' to rectify and you should be ok:

```
$ dos2unix.exe script.sh

dos2unix: converting file script.sh to Unix format...
```

Then rerun your script and those error messages should no longer appear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have the script file under a non-unix format
you can use:

```
vi new_name_for_your_script
```

and do a copy-paste ( you're running over windows )

your problem will be solved.